# Any way to auto switch on/off my hdd drives to save power?

Tags: hard-drive

I am running an 8 HDD drive server on an ubuntu server. They are always at max speed(7200r) and generating a lot of heat. Since I am not probing all 8 drives simultaneously, is there a way to kind of make my HDD enter a "power saving mode"?

Comment: If not accessed they should spin down in about 15 mins.

Comment: Does unmounting and then waiting until they spin down help?